Duplicate OrderId Generation in multi threading environment
code:
  List<Future<Void>> processFutures = new ArrayList<>();
  for (BulkOrderData readData : bulkOrderDataList) {


 processFutures.add(processExcutorService.submit(() -> {

                        try {
                            PushOrderDataResponse placeOrderResponse=bulkPushOrderTransactionalService.pushOrderData(readData, productRefMap.get(readData.getItemData().get(0).getProductReference()), countryCode);
                            readData.setOrderId(placeOrderResponse.getOrderId() != null ? String.valueOf(placeOrderResponse.getOrderId()) : "NA");
                            readData.setUploadRemark(placeOrderResponse.getMessage());
                            // return null;

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                            readData.setOrderId(null);
                            readData.setUploadRemark("Error we got during placing this order, Please connect to technical team");

                            logger.error("Error we got during push order in databse",e);

                        }
                        return null;


                    }));
//code....
}}

it is the code showing from where i am calling my method pushOrderData(//argument) in separate class  asa this method is called by multiple thread.
//data saving class


@Service
public class BulkPushOrderTransactionalService {


//method for saving 
 @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class )
    public synchronized PushOrderDataResponse  pushOrderData(BulkOrderData orderData, CassandraApiResponseReader cassandraApiResponseReader, String countryCode) throws Exception {

            int startOrderId = 100001;
            Integer resMaxOrderIdRes=0;
            try {
                resMaxOrderIdRes = orderRepository.findOrderIdByOrderSource();
                //resMaxOrderIdRes = generateOrderId();


            }
             catch (Exception e)
            {

                    throw new RuntimeException("Transaction failed in saving ", e);



            }

           if(resMaxOrderIdRes!=null && resMaxOrderIdRes!=0)
            {
                startOrderId=resMaxOrderIdRes;

            }


//new order id created by getting max order id firstly 

            newOrderId=startOrderId+1;

            CustomerOrderDao customerOrderDao=new CustomerOrderDao();
            customerOrderDao.setOrderId(newOrderId);
           

            //more data setting


             ///saving data corrosponding to new order id 

            try{
                orderRepository.save(customerOrderDao);
                //orderDataService.sa
                // veOrder(customerOrderDao);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error("error in saving data in customer order table{}", e);
                response.setCode(404);
                response.setMessage("Error we got during placing this order, Please connect to technical team");
                response.setStatus("error");
                throw new RuntimeException("Transaction failed in saving customer item history", e);



            }


// 4 more dao call where i am saving data

}}

As you see in code i am trying to save data in database, and data is of size 500 and i am calling that push method that save data to database from multithreaded environment so inside push method i am firstly fetching max orderId(let say from order table) then add one to it to make new orderID and save data to database for that  new orderId (let say firstly in order table from where i get max orderId) and saving data in 4 5 other tables also.
the problem i am facing is i am getting duplicate orderid as it is called by multiple thread and same orderId from table(order) read by multiple thread and make new orderId by adding one.
as i marked method synchronized but problem not solved
i do not want to make orderId unique in database i am using mysql data base.
if i am doing it without multi-threading it is taking 2.5 to 3 minutes to  save 500 record with multi-threading 10-12 second but problem is of duplicate orderid
reading 500 data from csv file with more than 35 theader (column)
I need an application level solution.

Why not let the database handle the creation of order ids by creating a sequence on the database-size?

Please indent your code in a generally accepted way to make it more readable

@Turing85 I want to handle the scenario on application level not on db level, please suggest solution on application level

MySQL manual: 5.6.9 Using AUTO_INCREMENT

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The problem lies in the database. The synchronization problem you are running into, is the interaction between:

Ask the DB what the current highest order ID is in the table.
Create a new row in the table, using an order ID supplied by your java code.

This process requires that the DB treats each insertion as a whole, fully committed transaction, which it can do, but which is unbelievably slow. A lot slower than just doing it serially.
The unfortunate conclusion is that your setup is fundamentally broken. As in, with the way you've set it up, your code is either going to be incredibly slow and vastly slower than much simpler takes on the idea (such as just doing it all single threaded) would be, or, it is broken and fails to generate unique IDs. In any case, it is likely to be far slower than it could be even if you did accept the order ID errors or let the DB solve the order ID problem.
Background - DBs and threads
DBs need to save his stuff to disk, and needs to ensure that no 2 transactions get in the way of each other.
The benefit of parallellizing, assuming the cores are right there and freely available, is not quite equal to simply 'hey if I have 4 cores and I smear a job across all of them, it runs 4 times faster yay!' - because there's a tax to pay: The tax of interconnection. If one core needs to coordinate work with another, that costs time.
For DBs, that interconnection aspect tends to be quite large (that whole 'it all ends up on a disk, which is either strictly sequential (rotating metal), or at least significantly interconnected, and I need to crosscheck transactions with each other to ensure they don't clash. Which is interconnection perse, and in this case significantly say because the various transactions are writing rows into the same table').
Hence, the actual benefit of inserting massive amounts of data into a db table by using threads is extremely limited.
Split your jobs
Given the above, if this part of your code:

readData.setOrderId(placeOrderResponse.getOrderId() != null ? String.valueOf(placeOrderResponse.getOrderId()) : "NA");
readData.setUploadRemark(placeOrderResponse.getMessage());


Takes no time (and it shouldn't set methods generally shouldn't take ages of time) then the answer is simple:
Simple answer 1 - forget about it!
Just make this code single threaded. It sounds like perhaps, possibly, this is what happened:

You wrote it single threaded
You or someone in your team observed that it seemed slow.
You incorrectly think that 'parallel code is fast'.
Based on that incorrect thinking, you decided the way to address the 'it is slow!' issue is to parallelize the code.
You are now asking questions about how to do that, and why it isn't working.

The problem here is that you are asking questions about an irrelevant side track. Because parallellizing is not how you make this go any faster. Or.. it might be. It depends on what DB engine you are using. But, usually, due to the fundamental informatics issue of how the benefits of parallelizing suffer when an highly interconnected process is part of the job, it won't be the answer.
If the above snippet is a lengthy process (say, as part of that set method some API is called), then the best way to tackle this problem is to fully separate it out. One thread writes to the DB (and will assign order IDs, thus, fixing the problem, as now only one thread is doing it), and a pool of threads does the parallellizable job of API calls.
At which point we've reduced the job of the database part of the task to a single thread regardless of the answer: If these set methods are fast, just.. stick to one thread. If these set methods are slow, parallelize only that, not the database work.
Now we get to, how do I insert quickly:
More complicated answer 2 - Goldilocks transactions
Committing is slow. Having humongous transactions is slow.
This results in a weird goldilocks situation. This is a really slow way to insert a million rows into a database:

Start a transaction.
Insert 1 row.
commit the transaction.
Loop this 1 million times.

Because a commit() is heavy duty! The DB generally needs to adhere to its promises of 'longevity' (it needs to ensure that this data is truly saved before telling the agent that called COMMIT that the commit has succeeded) - this involves this long chain of e.g. asking the disk that it is truly done writing this data and it is now, barring hardware faults, 'safe'. The idea is: If someone trips over a power cable a microsecond after COMMIT returns, the data should still be safe. So, the DB can't keep this one row in memory for a while, as an example. If the DB is set up to replicate (send its commits over to another backup DB), and it's in 'safe replication' mode, it has to wait for the backup DB to report that it has fully committed (including it having to wait for disk to report it's all safely stored), and so on.
That sounds like we should commit as little as possible. But this:

Open a transaction
Write a row to the DB.
Do that 1 million more times.
Commit the transaction

Is often also slow. The DB tends to store transactions as a sort of 'todo list' that can be integrated into the main DB data structures later (when COMMIT is called), and often that integration is relatively tricky, so if the system is busy, the 'todo list' might remain in that form even if you COMMIT, at which point all other transactions need to adjust their workings based on all 'commited but not yet integrated transaction todo lists'. This system all works great.. until those todo list grow to ridiculous size. How slow this actually becomes depends on a ton of factors - for example, many DB systems won't use indices on these todo lists which is irrelevant... unless that todo list is humongous.
The point is, making humongous todo lists is dangerous for performance. It might cause problems. It might not. Best to avoid them. Hence, we get into goldilocks insertion. This is how you should do it:

Start a transaction.
Write a row.
Do that... at most 500 more times or so.
Commit.
Loop until all rows are written.

Where the sweet spot is usually a 'band' (i.e. committing 200 at a time is about as fast as comitting 1000 at a time) but the exact start and end point of the goldilocks golden band depends on factors. Usually, just go with 500 and don't revisit unless it really does run slower than you feel it should.
Very complex answer 3 - Use DB fast insert functionality
The job of 'I have millions of rows of data and it allll needs to go into this database table' comes up a lot. Hence, many DB engines have support for it. This is, pretty much always, a significantly faster way to insert a ton of data. Often this is not done via INSERT, but via COPY, or by starting and ending the transaction with a 'bulk copy mode on' / 'bulk copy mode off' command. Usually in bulk copy mode, all transactional guarantees are eliminated (so, you can't fast-insert unless you have the DB all to yourself), and the DB is the one that will engage all the cores (so you do not run a fast insert in a multithreaded environment - let the DB do that! - and if it doesn't, probably it doesn't because that wouldn't make it go any faster).
The reason it's so much faster is e.g. that the DB does not need to update any indices during the bulk insert job, and will only do so at the end.
Imagine you have a town of 5 million people, and 1 million people move in. You COULD accept 1 person moving in and update the local phone book, which requires moving many, many people around, as the phone book is in alphabetical order. And then do that 999,999 more times.
Or, you forget about the phone book for a moment, move all 1 million people in, and then just rewrite the whole phone book from scratch; all 6 million entries. Which is going to be orders of magnitude faster than inserting one name in an arbitrary place in the phone book 1 million times. Literally - instead of writing about 6 million entries in a phone book, you'd have to write on average 2.5 BILLION entries. That's one example of how DBs can be way, way faster if you use a bulk insertion mode.
Unfortunately, JDBC does not directly expose bulk copy mode reliably, it's fairly weird syntax even if you do, many systems like hibernate don't support it well, and more generally the way to do it is very very different between different DB engines. So, if you want to use this, check the manual of your DB, and ditch hibernate for this part.
